# AWS CDK [Python]: Why are my CIDR blocks conflicting in a new VPC with only new Subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've created a VPC and three subnets:

public1a: '10.0.1.0/24'
private1a: '10.0.2.0/24'
private1b: '10.0.3.0/24'

The VPC is completely new, as indicative by the LOG that shows its newly created. So there aren't any preexisting subnets to conflict with.

It seems as though the CDK is trying to create the subnets twice, and they are conflicting with themselves.

LOG:

```
TestNet: deploying... [1/1]
TestNet: creating CloudFormation changeset...
TestNet |  0/21 | 8:40:11 AM | REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | TestNet User Initiated
TestNet |  0/21 | 8:40:16 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | TestNet User Initiated
TestNet |  0/21 | 8:40:19 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::VPC                         | VPC (VPCB9E5F0B4)
TestNet |  0/21 | 8:40:19 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata                    | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata)
TestNet |  0/21 | 8:40:20 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata                    | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:20 AM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CDK::Metadata                    | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:20 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::VPC                         | VPC (VPCB9E5F0B4) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:31 AM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::EC2::VPC                         | VPC (VPCB9E5F0B4)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PrivateSubnetA/RouteTable (PrivateSubnetARouteTable6864ED5E)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PublicSubnet/Subnet (PublicSubnet1C95672B)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | VPC/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTable (VPCPrivateSubnet1RouteTableBE8A6027)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PrivateSubnetB/RouteTable (PrivateSubnetBRouteTableDB39B19C)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PrivateSubnetB/Subnet (PrivateSubnetBSubnet62CC049A)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PublicSubnet/RouteTable (PublicSubnetRouteTable568ED6F0)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PrivateSubnetA/Subnet (PrivateSubnetASubnet0C8C29C1)
TestNet |  2/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | VPC/PublicSubnet1/RouteTable (VPCPublicSubnet1RouteTableFEE4B781)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:37 AM | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CDK::Metadata                    | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | VPC/PublicSubnet1/Subnet (VPCPublicSubnet1SubnetB4246D30)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | VPC/PrivateSubnet1/Subnet (VPCPrivateSubnet1Subnet8BCA10E0)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:32 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role                        | Custom::VpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProvider/Role (CustomVpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProviderRole26592FE0)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PrivateSubnetA/RouteTable (PrivateSubnetARouteTable6864ED5E) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | VPC/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTable (VPCPrivateSubnet1RouteTableBE8A6027) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role                        | Custom::VpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProvider/Role (CustomVpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProviderRole26592FE0) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PublicSubnet/RouteTable (PublicSubnetRouteTable568ED6F0) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PrivateSubnetB/Subnet (PrivateSubnetBSubnet62CC049A) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | VPC/PublicSubnet1/RouteTable (VPCPublicSubnet1RouteTableFEE4B781) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PublicSubnet/Subnet (PublicSubnet1C95672B) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PrivateSubnetA/Subnet (PrivateSubnetASubnet0C8C29C1) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PrivateSubnetB/RouteTable (PrivateSubnetBRouteTableDB39B19C) Resource creation Initiated
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:33 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | VPC/PublicSubnet1/Subnet (VPCPublicSubnet1SubnetB4246D30) Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '10.0.0.0/17' conflicts with another subnet (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 38a8be54-b2c5-44e8-adfa-8562d155a13e)" (RequestToken: 60d0890b-1f18-b791-9f40-8faea8d4c3ed, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PrivateSubnetA/RouteTable (PrivateSubnetARouteTable6864ED5E) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PrivateSubnetB/Subnet (PrivateSubnetBSubnet62CC049A) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PublicSubnet/RouteTable (PublicSubnetRouteTable568ED6F0) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | VPC/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTable (VPCPrivateSubnet1RouteTableBE8A6027) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | VPC/PublicSubnet1/RouteTable (VPCPublicSubnet1RouteTableFEE4B781) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::RouteTable                  | PrivateSubnetB/RouteTable (PrivateSubnetBRouteTableDB39B19C) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PrivateSubnetA/Subnet (PrivateSubnetASubnet0C8C29C1) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | PublicSubnet/Subnet (PublicSubnet1C95672B) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EC2::Subnet                      | VPC/PrivateSubnet1/Subnet (VPCPrivateSubnet1Subnet8BCA10E0) Resource creation cancelled
TestNet |  1/21 | 8:40:34 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role                        | Custom::VpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProvider/Role (CustomVpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProviderRole26592FE0) Resource creation cancelled
```

STACK:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as s3
import aws_cdk as cdk


class NetworkingStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.App, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # Create a VPC
        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, 'VPC',
            ip_addresses=ec2.IpAddresses.cidr("10.0.0.0/16"),
            max_azs=1,
            create_internet_gateway=False
        )
        
        # Create public subnet
        public_subnet = ec2.Subnet(self, 'PublicSubnet',
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            availability_zone='us-west-1a',
            cidr_block='10.0.1.0/24',
            #subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        )

        # Create private subnet a
        private_subnet_a = ec2.Subnet(self, 'PrivateSubnetA',
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            availability_zone='us-west-1a',
            cidr_block='10.0.2.0/24',
            #subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        )

        # Create private subnet b
        private_subnet_b = ec2.Subnet(self, 'PrivateSubnetB',
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            availability_zone='us-west-1b',
            cidr_block='10.0.3.0/24',
            #subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        )


app = cdk.App()
NetworkingStack(app, "TestNet")
app.synth()
```

Comment: If you don't supply `subnetConfiguration` when creating the VPC, the CDK will auto-create 1 private and 1 public subnet per AZ. You indicated max_azs=1 so it will auto-create 2 subnets (each with 1/2 of the VPC CIDR). You've then explicitly created another 3 subnets, making 5 in total. Solution is to use `subnetConfiguration`.